# Using logical vectors to replace if-else ladder in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, logic

I am writing code that will determine the tax values for various levels of income, based on given parameters:

- Taxable Income $10,000 or less: 

  tax is 10% of taxable income.
- Taxable income more than $10,000 and less than or equal to $20,000:

   tax is $1,000 + %20 of the amount by which the taxable income exceeds $10,000.
- Taxable income more then $20,000:

  tax is $3,000 + 50% of the amount by which the taxable income exceeds $20,000.

I want to test each case by displaying the correct values for the following incomes:

$5,000, $10,000, $11,000, $15,000, $30,000, and $100,000.

**Objectives**

- Solve the above problem statement with if-else ladders. I have completed this, see below.
- Solve the same problem statement again with logical vectors INSTEAD of if-else ladders.

**Code that I have so far**

I finished the first objective by finding the tax of each individual income with if-else ladders:

```
%% Setting up the Vector
A = [5000; 10000; 11000; 15000; 30000; 100000];
%% Now to calculate the Tax
loopend = size(A);      
for i=1: loopend
    income(i) = A(i);  %Sets the income equal to the values in vector A    
    if (income(i) <= 10000)
        tax{i} = 0.1*income(i) ;
    elseif (income(i) <= 20000)
        tax{i} = 1000+(0.2*(income(i)-10000)) ;
    elseif (income(i) > 20000)
        tax{i} = 3000+(0.5*(income(i)-20000)) ;
    end
end
%% Time to display our perfect results
display(tax);

%% But how do we do it with logical vectors instead?
```

I am lost on how to solve this by using logic vectors or logic structures (to be honest I'm not completely sure what that means). Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside: I would hate to get a pay rise from $19k to $20k in this tax system, it would be a pay *cut* of $2k... Are you sure those brackets are correct? Because they're certainly not realistic!

---

Firstly, some notes on your looping method, please see my comments:

```
% Use numel for a 1D array, or size(A,2) for number of columns. size(A) = [1, 2], not 2
loopend = numel(A);   
% Always try to initialise your output array to the desired size
tax = zeros(1, loopend)
% Try to avoid using i or j as a loop variable, i=j=sqrt(-1) by default in MATLAB  
for ii=1:loopend
    % You were replicating A in the vector income, either just use A(ii) or set to a scalar 
    income = A(ii);      
    if (income <= 10000)
        % tax is a numerical array, not a cell array, use parentheses () not braces {}
        tax(ii) = 0.1*income;
    elseif (income <= 20000)
        tax(ii) = 1000+(0.2*(income-10000)) ;
    elseif (income > 20000)
        tax(ii) = 3000+(0.5*(income-20000)) ;
    end
end
```

I'm not sure why you've written "logical vectors (structures)", since structures and local vectors are different data types in MATLAB! A [structure](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) is a broad data type, which wouldn't really help you here. I believe the question is asking you to *structure your code logically* rather than *use the logical structure data type*.

Here is how I would solve this with logical arrays:

```
% lower limits of the tax brackets, and their corresponding costs.
taxbands = [0,    10000, 20000;
            0.1,  0.2,   0.5;
            0     1000,  3000];
% initialise output
tax = zeros(1, numel(A));
% Assign result per tax band
for ii = 1:size(taxbands,2)
    % Get the logical indices of incomes at (or above) this tax band
    idx = (A > taxbands(1,ii));
    % Calculate tax for all incomes in this band
    tax(idx) = taxbands(3,ii) + taxbands(2,ii)*(A(idx)-taxbands(1,ii));
end
```

You could make the latter code more efficient by having an upper bound as well when creating `idx`, perhaps using `inf` as the highest upper bound, so that you're not also working out all previous brackets for each income.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The values for taxation were a given for the assignment I am working on, and you are correct they are very unrealistic!